# Der Genitiv französischer Nomen

Tags: genitive

Im Deutschen gibt es französische Toponyme, Familiennamen usw., deren französische Aussprache unverändert blieb. Das heißt, Endungen sind stumm geblieben.

**Frage 1.** Wie bildet man den Genitiv für solche französischen Nomen?

Um die Frage ein bisschen zu beschränken, betrachte man das Toponym *Cannes* und den Namen *Villeret*, die stumme Endungen haben:

> `Genitiv von Villeret` Witz war nie auf `Genitiv von Cannes` rotem Teppich.

Meine Vermutung lautet

> Villerets Witz war nie auf Cannes rotem Teppich.

**Frage 2**. Wie soll das ausgesprochen werden?

Für kurze Sätze weiß ich schon, dass der Genitiv einfach vermieden werden könnte. Ebendas will ich nicht. Denn für längere Texte kann man sich nicht so einfach vom Genitiv fernhalten.

(Als Randnotiz frage ich mich, ob das Dilemma genau im Namen "Internationale Filmfestspiele von Cannes" vermieden wurde.)

---

*Bemerkung 1.* Ich muss einen kurzen Text schreiben, in dem ständig ein französisches Nomen mit Endung *-es* erscheinen soll. Daher die Frage.

*Bemerkung 2.* Wenn der Satz im Beispiel sinnwidrig klingt, bearbeite ich die Frage.

Comment: Die Frage ist super - weil es vielen wohl ähnlich geht. Ich fand auch die beiden Zusätze, die Du inzwischen gelöscht hast, ganz gut. Vielleicht fügst Du die doch wieder ein? :)

Comment: Ich überlege gerade, ob man sich die Fragen nicht in umgekehrter Reihenfolge stellen sollte: (1) Wie lautet der Genitiv; (2) Wie schreibe ich das? // Wenn ich ein Wort mit der Aussprache /Willerreh/ nehme und vor mich hinspreche, ist der Genitiv für mich intuitiv /Willerrehs/. In Anlehnung an die Scheibweise des Singulars würde ich das dann als `Villerets` schreiben.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Direkt aus den offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln (§ 96(1)):

> Eigennamen, deren Grundform (Nominativform) auf einen s-Laut (geschrieben: *-s, -ss, -ß, -tz, -z, -x, -ce)* endet, bekommen im Genitiv den Apostroph, wenn sie nicht einen Artikel, ein Possessivpronomen oder dergleichen bei sich haben:
>   […]
>   E2: Der Apostroph steht auch, wenn *-s, -z, -x* usw. in der Grundform stumm sind: *Cannes’ Filmfestspiele, Boulez’ bedeutender Beitrag, Giraudoux’ Werke*

*Villeret* bekommt ein ganz normales Genitiv-s angehängt. Also:

> **Villerets** Witz war nie auf dem roten Teppich **Cannes’**.

In beiden Fällen wird das *s* am Ende ausgesprochen und die Aussprache des Namens sonst unverändert gelassen.

---

PS: Um Missverständnisse auszuschließen, würde ich (in gesprochener Sprache eher als in geschriebener) in den meisten Fällen vermeiden, derartige Namen in den Genitiv zu setzen – aber eben nur in den meisten. Zum Beispiel im folgenden Satz ist der Genitiv m. E. das geringste Übel:

> Ich hole Francois’ Paket von der Post ab.

Comment: Wunderbar. Darf ich fragen, wo findet man die sog. offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln? Und spricht man *s* aus, aber das *t* denn bleib stumm, oder?

Comment: @c.p.: 1) [Hier](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/) (und die sind werden nicht nur offiziell *genannt.* Die *sind* so offiziell, wie irgend möglich). 2) Ja, ich würde das *t* stumm lassen (sofern es denn in der Originalaussprache des Namens stumm ist).

Comment: Ich frage mich, was ist gegen "von Cannes" einzuwenden. Da verbiegt man sich, um einen Genitiv von Cannes zu bilden. Warum diese Umstände? "von Cannes" ist genauso gut und viel einfacher. Da spürt man schon eine seit langem vorherrschende Meinung, die Umschreibung mit "von" sei etwas Schlechtes. Unser Deutschlehrer sprach vom "schlechten Genitiv". Ich halte das für eine völlig irrige Meinung. Im Englischen gibt es den s-Genitiv und den of-Genitiv. Aber niemand würde sagen, der of-Genitiv sei schlecht.

Comment: Wrzlprmft + @c.p.: Grundsätzlich richtig - aber das Ende des Beispielsatzes ist ausgesprochen grauenhaft... kein Mensch würde das so sagen. Allenfalls könnte man "Cannes' roten Teppich" schreiben - aber selbst das klingt in meinen Ohren wie eine schlechte Übersetzung. "...auf dem roten Teppich von Cannes" ist hier definitiv die bessere Lösung.

Comment: @rogermue + Mac: Wenn Ihr in die Frage schaut, solltet ihr sehen, dass es hier gerade nicht darum geht, was schöner ist, sondern wie man den »normalen Genitiv« bilden würde.

Comment: @Mac + rogermue. Danke sehr. Ich habe immer Schwierigkeiten, das beste Beispiel zu finden. Ich habe nicht zwei, sondern nur ein Beispiel gegeben, um eine weitschweifige Frage zu vermeiden. Dazu passte Villeret zu Cannes. Über diese werde ich aber eigentlich nicht schreiben.

Comment: Be fremden Wörtern unterläßt man es normalerweise, einen Genitiv zu bilden. Und wenn man mit dem Genitiv sowieso in Schwierigkeiten kommt, weil er zudem noch auf -s endet, sollte man nicht von normalem Genitiv sprechen. Und es geht nicht um schöner, sondern hier geht es wirklich um was ist normal und was ist unnormal.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Wie gesagt - grundsätzlich richtig, allerdings finde ich einen Hinweis schon wichtig, dass eines der beiden Beispiele, mit denen die Regel verdeutlicht wird, an dieser Stelle unidiomatisch ist. Vielleicht könntest Du zumindest die Wortstellung ändern? (Zu "... auf Cannes' rotem Teppich".) Der nachgestellte Genitiv ist superschräg :)

Comment: @Mac in der Frage habe ich das schon geändert.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Ich habe nicht von schöner gesprochen. Ich finde Cannes' geradezu unnormal, mag es auch nach Duden sein. Normalerweise wird von ausländischen Wörtern kein deutscher s-Genitiv gebildert. Und meine Meinung ist, das Normale wäre hier "von Cannes".

Comment: @rogermue: *Annormal* im Sinne von *selten:* ja. *Annormal* im Sinne von *unmöglich:* Meines Erachtens nicht. Ich füge dennoch mal eine Bemerkung ein, die Dir aber nicht gefallen wird. In jedem Fall ist es nicht üblich, den Genitiv bei allen fremden Namen zu unterlassen – man braucht sich z. B. nur irgendwas über Obama anzuschauen. Mal ganz abgesehen davon, dass die viele vermeintlich deutsche Eigennamen anderen Sprachen entstammen.

Comment: *mea culpa* :) danke auch für letzten Kommentar.

Answer (score -3):

Ich habe noch nie gesehen: Die Museen Paris' oder Paris' Museen.

Comment: Ich glaube ihre Kommentaren unter der anderen Antwort waren echt gut. Vielleicht wünschen Sie ihre Antwort damit vervollständigen?

Comment: Eine etwas ausführlichere Erläuterung, weshalb der "von Genitiv" hier gebräuchlicher ist, wäre schön. So wie es jetzt steht, ist es nämlich eher ein Kommentar denn eine Antwort.